# Render React component as static public HTML in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a React component that I would like to convert to a static HTML file when my next.js app builds. Let's say what I want to convert is just this:

```
<MyGallery columns={4} />
```

This component is not interactive, so no JavaScript is needed. Let's say it only renders some images as a list:

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
    ... more images
</div>
```

If it's possible to alter this HTML, even better. In perfect case, I'd be able to export it as a public JavaScript script for embedding:

```js
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = `
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="1.jpg">
        <img src="2.jpg">
        <img src="3.jpg">
        ... more images
    </div>
`;
```

So whenever my app is being built, it would compile the above JavaScript file. I have no idea how to do it. Building a custom page just for this purpose? But then how to get rid of the surrounding layout code? It doesn't seem possible with Next.js. Or maybe should it be some kind of custom script?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're goal is, but you can serve this file from a CDN or from the Next [public](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) folder and embed it. Since it doesn't need React state and it doesn't need to be interactive, I'd recommend keeping it separate from the **React** application entirely. For instance, this [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/script-loading-i5ggk?file=/pages/_document.js) utilizes the public folder with a custom [_document.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) file to load a static Javascript file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just create a pure (stateless) function component and achieve the same result.

Comment: @MattCarlotta the thing is, I'm using the same MyGallery component elsewhere in my app. It's not completely static, since there are Sass styles involved and props. So I would need to render it as a partial, preferably a raw JavaScript file with `fetch()` in it to be embedded on other pages.

Comment: If this component needs to accept props then it can still be a pure function component. If it doesn’t need to interact with the react app at all, then you can create a JavaScript widget. When it comes to selective usage based on route, then there’s an [RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18172) for script loading.

Comment: It is already a function component. But I'm not sure if we understand each other. I'm talking about compiling the component to some sort of custom content.

Comment: I think I understand now… you want a **component** instead of a **page** to be statically generated to HTML. Then no, Next only statically optimizes pages with components.

Comment: That said, you could create a mini next app with just this component and statically export it as an index page. Then embed it within the main app within an iframe. Just not sure if it’ll be practical in terms of its purpose (requires its own dependencies, own server, own domain and so on just to serve a single static html file).

Comment: The point of this is to get rid of an iframe actually. That's why I thought of doing that via script.